# Android Hide Keyboard Not Working - cannot hide soft keyboard

Tags: android, hide, soft-keyboard

I'm developing on the Droid Incredible (and have tested on a 1.5 AVD Emulator as well), and one of the tabs in my tab widget consists of a listview and a row with an EditText and a Send button (for a chat feature). I am using the following to close the soft keyboard once I click Send, but it's not working. This is identical to code I've found elsewhere that people have upvoted as correct.

See anything I'm missing?

```
// in Button's onClick():
EditText chatTextBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.chat_entry);
// Handle button click ...
chatTextBox.setText("");

InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(chatTextBox.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
```

I also tried changing the flag to 0. No luck. Anyone know what's up??

****EDIT**** Just realized I was originally using `hideSoftInputFromInputMethod()` instead of `hideSoftInputFromWindow()`. Changing it didn't make it work though...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Changing HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY to 0 did it (after I changed to`hideSoftInputFromWindow()` from of `hideSoftInputFromInputMethod()`).

However I'm not sure why HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY isn't working since I am not explicitly opening the keyboard with a long press on Menu.

Comment: If you will show keyboard with flag `SHOW_FORCED`then it indicates that the user has forced the input method open (such as by long-pressing menu) so it should not be closed until they explicitly do so. [See Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html#SHOW_FORCED)

Comment: If you have **Forced** shown keyboard and want to hide then use following code `InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);  imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(mEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);`

Answer (score 18):

**Another option to prevent it from activity in AndroidManifest.xml file**

android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" - This method will prevent loading/showing keyboard when the activity is loaded. But when you click the editable component like edittext the keyboard will open. 
perfect for my requirement.

```
<activity
            android:name=".Name"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden">
```

Comment: this is working when keyboard is never dying somehow. good one.

Comment: I started witn <activity...android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"> and that worked on all my test devices except for my amazon fire.  <activity...android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"> works on all devices including the amazon fire.

Answer (score 14):

1.first bind your edit text token with keyboard and open 
  i.e `inputMethodManager.showSoftInput(_edittext, 0);` //here _edittext is instance of view

2.keyboard will get hidden automatically if the edit text goes hidden from the screen

3.edit text is still on screen but you want to hide the keyboard then use below code
`imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(_edittext.getWindowToken(), 0);` //this won't work if edittext is not on screen or not focused.

Answer (score 1):

This works good for me:

```
fun FragmentActivity.openKeyboard(){
    val imm: InputMethodManager = this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
    imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT, 0) // do not use SHOW_FORCED here
}
fun FragmentActivity.hideKeyboard(view: View){ // send any view here, for instance page root view
    val imm: InputMethodManager = this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.windowToken, 0)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing in onResume/onCreate:

```
rootView.requestFocus();
```

rootView is your main view. This will change the focus away from the EditText.