# Up the virtual keyboard

Tags: android, android-virtual-keyboard

I ran into a situation where a virtual keyboard displayed

1) When setting the listener:

```
rssURLTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rssURL);

        rssURLTV.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            // @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                feedUrl = (String) rssURLTV.getText().toString();

                Intent intent = new Intent("urss.database_table");
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
```

2) and activity started
....

**for these situations, I do not want display a virtual keyboard**

Comment: May be related links at the right column could help you? http://imgur.com/1H95x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this for hiding  virtual keyboard  in Current Activity:

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2796231/hide-soft-keyboard-not-working  (Does not work)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215476/hide-virtual-keyboard-in-android?rq=1  (Does not work)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836801/hide-virtual-keyboard-always?rq=1 (WORK)

Answer (score 3):

You can try putting

```
<activity android:name=".Main"
          android:label="@string/app_name"
          android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
          >
```

in the android manifest